# go import github, how to set up?

Tags: import, go, package

trying to run a go test code and have this issue.
It has import like this:

```
"github.com/abcd/abcd"
```

Then, when I run it, it failed to find the package.

I noticed this is a common practice to import github stuff like this.
For me, what is the right the way to handle it?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the package from the command line using: `go get github.com/abcd/abcd`

Comment: oh nice! @ANisus this is a magic. what happened.

Comment: `go get` is how you download and install packages and dependencies. You can read more about it here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should download the repository inside your gopath

```
mkdir -P $PWD/gopath/{bin,src,pkg}

export GOPATH=$PWD/gopath:$GOPATH

go get "github.com/abcd/abcd"

ls gopath/src/github.com/abcd/abcd
```

If you tell us what specific repository you may get more accurate info on how to accomplish your task